# Minkowski Distance Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given compact sets $A$, $B$, define the Minkowski distance between the two sets as:

$$ \delta(A,B):= \inf \{ r: B \subseteq \mathscr{N}_r (A) \, \, \text{and} \, \, A \subseteq \mathscr{N}_r (B) \}$$

with $$ \mathscr{N}_r (A) := \bigcup_{x \in A} \mathscr{N}_r(x)$$It is easy enough to show that this metric satisfies the needed axioms, but my question is as follows:
why do the sets need to be compact?

Comment: @copper.hat Is $\delta(A,B) = 0$ if, say $A:= (c,a)$, $B=(a,d)$?

Comment: @copper.hat Ahh yes, thank you. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Isn't this the Hausdorff distance?

Answer (score 0):

We need at least closed sets, as otherwise (in $\mathbb{R}$, e.g.) $\delta(A,B) = 0$ for $A = (0,1), B = [0,1]$, while the sets are different.

We need compactness in order for there to be at least one $r > 0$ such that $A \subseteq \mathcal{N}_r(B)$ and $B \subseteq \mathcal{N}_r(A)$; in fact we need boundedness for that. Otherwise we don't have such an $r$ for $A = (-\infty, -1]$ and $B = [1, \infty)$, in the reals again, and the distance would not be defined.